# Check if string contains a range of numbers

Tags: c++, string

I'd like to test a `std::string` for containing numbers of any range e.g `5 to 35` in a `std::string s = "XDGHYH20YFYFFY"` would there be function or I would have to convert a number to string and then use a loop to find each one?

Comment: I think what you need here is a regular expression.

Comment: Are you trying to find at least one number between the range or all the numbers in the range? If it is the first one I think using Regex will be better but if you will check for all of the numbers in the range than use find function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd probably use a locale that treated everything except digits as white-space, and read the numbers from a stringstream imbued with that locale and check if they're in range:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

struct digits_only: std::ctype<char> 
{
    digits_only(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::space);

        std::fill(&rc['0'], &rc['9'], std::ctype_base::digit);
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

bool in_range(int lower, int upper, std::string const &input) { 
    std::istringstream buffer(input);
    buffer.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new digits_only()));

    int n;

    while (buffer>>n)
        if (n < lower || upper < n)
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << in_range(5, 35, "XDGHYH20YFYFFY");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As much as some people are going to immediately go to regex on this, I think your best bet is actually a hybrid solution. Use REGEX to find numbers, then parse them and see if they're in range.

Something like this in C#. Not sure what regex libraries are available to you in C++.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection;

private static const Regex NUMBER_REGEX = new Regex(@"\d+")

public static bool ContainsNumberInRange(string str, int min, int max)
{
    MatchCollection matches = NUMBER_REGEX.Matches(str);
    foreach(Match match in matches)
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(match.Value);
        if (value >= min && value <= max)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You could use boost::regex in C++.  I'm not sure about the `\d+` expression; you can be more precise. For instance, the range 3-35 would be found more efficiently with `\d{1,2}` (assuming that X200Y matches)

Comment: I assumed that X200Y should not match, because that should parse as 200, which is not in range. The problem wasn't specified well enough to know this for sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for all of the numbers in the range then use string::find function in a loop. Here is the reference for the function:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Also do you want to use the numbers in the string only once? For example SDFSD256fdsfs will give you the numbers 2 5 6 25 56 256 if you don't remove them from the string after each match.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this iteratively with a `stringstream` object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>

void check (std::string& s) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);

    std::cout << "Searching string: " << s << std::endl;
    while (ss) {

        while (ss && !isdigit(ss.peek ()))
            ss.get ();

        if (! ss)
            break;

        int i = 0;
        ss >> i;
        std::cout << "  Extraced value: " << i << std::endl;

    }
}


int main () {

    std::string s1 = "XDGHYH20YFYFFY";
    std::string s2 = "20YF35YFFY100";
    check (s1);
    check (s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Yields:

```
Searching string: XDGHYH20YFYFFY
  Extraced value: 20
Searching string: 20YF35YFFY100
  Extraced value: 20
  Extraced value: 35
  Extraced value: 100
```

Adding parameters to the `check` function to limit the results accepted would be trivial.