# get atof to continue converting a string to a number after the first non valid ch in a string

Tags: c++, string

i'd like to know if there a way to get atof continue converting to number even if there are non valid charcters in the way

for example let say i have string "444-3-3-33"
i want to covert it to a double a=4443333
(and keep the string as it was)
happy to get any suggestions or an alternative way

thanks!

Comment: And what languages would you be asking about?

Comment: (You should properly @address comment replies for them to show up in others people' responses tab.) That's what tags are for!

Comment: note too that after the edit of the question, my answer below will now be 'no'.  (it is not possible to get atof to read/convert a number with embedded non-numerics)

Answer (score 3):

I can't take credit for this solution, though it's a good one, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096042/check-if-string-contains-a-range-of-numbers) SO post.  For those too lazy to skip over, the author recommends using a locale to treat all non-numeric digits as whitespace.  It might be overkill for your solution but the idea is easily adaptable.  Instead of all non-numeric, you could just use "-" as your whitespace.  Here's his code, not mine.  Please, if you like this give *him* the upvote.

```
struct digits_only: std::ctype<char> 
{
    digits_only(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::space);

        std::fill(&rc['0'], &rc['9'], std::ctype_base::digit);
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

bool in_range(int lower, int upper, std::string const &input) { 
    std::istringstream buffer(input);
    buffer.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new digits_only()));

    int n;

    while (buffer>>n)
        if (n < lower || upper < n)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then just remove the whitespace and pass the string to `atof`.

Comment: @Steve Townsend thanks, I'm a big believer in credit where credit due.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the following strip out non-digits for me

```
bool no_digit(char ch) {return !std::isdigit(ch);}

std::string read_number(const std::string& input)
{
    std::string result;
    std::remove_copy_if( input.begin()
                       , input.end()
                       , std::back_inserter(result)
                       , &no_digit);
    return result;
}
```

---

```
std::string read_number(std::istream& is)
{
    std::string result;
    for(;;) {
        while(is.good() && !std::isdigit(is.peek()))
            is.get();
        if(!is.good())
            return result;
        result += is.get();
    }
    assert(false);
}
```

You can then read number using string streams:

```
std::istringstream iss(read_number("444-3-3-33");
int i;
if( !(iss>>i) ) throw "something went wrong!";
std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Comment: Rewriting the reverse of is_digit?  Couldn't you use `not1` and `ptr_fun` instead?

Comment: @wheaties: Yes, this would probably work. But then there might be implementations where `isdigit` is still a macro. (Just yesterday someone posted a question here about _beginning a new project_ with VC6.) Also, I find the current std lib's ways to bind clumsy at best. So I would have to drag boost into this small example... In the end I decided that a small function is easier.

Comment: @wheaties: I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `sscanf`

[edit]

upon further review, it would seem that you'll have to use `strstr` as `sscanf` could have an issue with the embedded '-'

further, the [page](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/string/strstr) should give you a good start on finding (and removing) your '-' char's

[/edit]

Comment: could you elaborate how can i use it?

Comment: ok i've read about strstr, but if i don't want to change my original string i would have to create a copy right?

Comment: you could, or the next option is to use strtok (even better suited to your purpose and non intrusive to the original string)

Answer (score 0):

copy the 'string number' to a local buffer(a `std::string`), then strip out the accepted chars from the number(compressing the string, as to not leave blank space, thus using `std::string.replace`), then call `atof` on `std::string.c_str`. alternatly you can use c strings, but then this wouldn't be C++.

alternatively, create a custom version of atof your self, using the source from say stdlibc or basic math.