# Separating alphabetic characters in C++ STL

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I've been practicing C++ for a competition next week. And in the sample problem I've been working on, requires splitting of paragraphs into words. Of course, that's easy. But this problem is so weird, that the words like: `isn't` should be separated as well: `isn` and `t`. I know it's weird but I have to follow this.

I have a function `split()` that takes a `constant char` delimiter as one of the parameter. It's what I use to separate words from spaces. But I can't figure out this one. Even numbers like: `phil67bs` should be separated as `phil` and `bs`.

And no, I don't ask for full code. A pseudocode will do, or something that will help me understand what to do. Thanks!

PS: Please no recommendations for external libs. Just the STL. :)

Comment: “I know it's weird” – it’s not (depending on the context of the algorithm).

Answer (score 4):

Filter out numbers, spaces and anything else that isn't a letter by using a proper locale.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096042/check-if-string-contains-a-range-of-numbers) SO thread about treating everything but numbers as a whitespace.  So use a [mask](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/ctype/mask/) and do something similar to what Jerry Coffin suggests but only for letters:

```
struct alphabet_only: std::ctype<char> 
{
    alphabet_only(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::space);

        std::fill(&rc['A'], &rc['['], std::ctype_base::upper);
        std::fill(&rc['a'], &rc['{'], std::ctype_base::lower);
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
```

And, boom!  You're golden.

Or... you could just do a transform:

```
char changeToLetters(const char& input){ return isalpha(input) ? input : ' '; }

vector<char> output;
output.reserve( myVector.size() );
transform( myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), insert_iterator(output), ptr_fun(changeToLetters) );
```

Which, um, is much easier to grok, just not as efficient as Jerry's idea.

Edit:

Changed 'Z' to '[' so that the value 'Z' is filled.  Likewise with 'z' to '{'.

Comment: You forgot to change the name of the locale. Otherwise, very good answer, learned something new (but why exactly are you using `std::list` in your second example? That’s horribly inefficient).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect job for the [`find_first_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) function which finds the first occurrence of a set of characters. You can use this to look for arbitrary stop characters and generate words from the spaces between such stop characters.

Roughly:

```
size_t previous = 0;
for (; ;) {
    size_t next = str.find_first_of(" '1234567890", previous);
    // Do processing
    if (next == string::npos)
        break;
    previous = next + 1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your function to delimit on anything that isn't an alphabetic character. Is there anything in particular that you are having trouble with?

Break down the problem: First, write a function that gets the first "word" from the sentence. This is easy; just look for the first non-alphabetic character. The next step is to remove all leading non-alphabetic character from the remaining string. From there, just repeat.

Comment: the function is using `getline()`, which takes a `const char` for the delimiter. And it would be so hard if I'll be doing so many `split()` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
vector<string> split(const string& str)
{
    vector<string> splits;

    string cur;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
        {
            if(!cur.empty())
            {
                splits.push_back(cur);
            }
            cur="";
        }
        else
        {
            cur += str[i];
        }
    }
    if(! cur.empty())
    {
        splits.push_back(cur);
    }

    return splits;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

let's assume that the input is in a `std::string` (use `std::getline(cin, line)` for example to read a full line from `cin`)

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string const& input)
{
  std::string::const_iterator it(input), end(input.end());
  std::string current;
  vector<std::string> words;
  for(; it != end; ++it)
  {
    if (isalpha(*it))
    { 
      current.push_back(*it); // add this char to the current word
    }
    else
    {
      // push the current word in to the result list
      words.push_back(current);
      current.clear(); // next word
    }
  }
  return words;
}
```

I've not tested it, but I guess it ought to work...

Comment: a couple of things to check: if there's a sequence of non-alpha's, you'll end up with an empty word being added for each. also, the last word may need adding to words before returning.

Comment: @Scott - it's an idea, and not full code.. ;) I'm sure the OP can fill in the blanks...