# How to read string of numbers from a file and put them in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, file, numbers

How can I save all the numbers from a text file in an array? For example:

> My name is Henry, I am 19 years old. I was born in 1992. 5ro2k.

The program should read the numbers 19, 1992, 5, 2 from the file and save them in an array. If the word is 52rok then it should read the number 52.

Comment: Not an *exact* duplicate, but [my answer to a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3096245/179910) still covers this quite nicely.

Comment: Some quick guidance. Write code to "open" a file, read line by line, convert string to int using atoi. And save the int in a array. Impressive 19 years old and have started asking questions on stackoverflow. Keep it up, but keep improving your quality of questions too. Dont give up.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I am stuck on how to read the values and what conditions to give to get the numeric values. The only way i know how to read a file is by `getc()`
`void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 FILE *fp;
 char ch;
        ary[100],i;
 fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
 while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF)
 {
  "some condition to check the numbers"
                ary(i)=ch;
                i++;
 }
 fclose(fp);
}`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to replace all characters except digits with spaces, and use strtok to tokenize the resulting string.

Here is a dirty pseudocodish example that you could modify to fit your needs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char s[] = "My name is Henry, I am 19 years old. I was born in 1992. 5ro2k.";
    char *p = s;
    while (*p) {
        if (!isdigit(*p)) {
            *p = ' ';
        }
        p++;
    }
    p = strtok(s, " ");
    while (p) {
        printf("%s\n", p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

The main thing that makes this example dirty is the use of `strtok`, which is not thread safe. You should use `strtok_r` instead. Of course you would need to parse the strings for integers yourself (`atoi` is a good choice for that).